Trouble trying to compile Vim on Rocky Linux
I cloned the github Vim repository, cd'ed into the vim directory and ran make but got this error:
checking whether stack_t has an ss_base field... no
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      On Linux that would be the libncurses-dev package.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.

I checked, and I do have ncurses installed. I tried to install it anyway:
# dnf install ncurses-libs
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:32 ago on Fri 16 Aug 2024 11:25:36 AM CDT.
Package ncurses-libs-6.1-10.20180224.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

And indeed I see the ncurses library installed in /usr/lib64
I read adding the -fPIC option would fix it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Okay, I figured it out. I found the tgetent() function defined in the tinfo library (by running nm -D file on all the library files in /usr/lib64 (where all the library files are stored on Rocky) until I found the one that had tgetent defined. The reason ld wasn't able to find it was because for some reason in /usr/lib64 there wasn't a symbolic link that went from libtinfo.so to libtinfo.so.6. The loader (ld) doesn't know to look for the library with a version number attached to the filename, so I had to create the symbolic link for it. There may be another way to resolve this, but this worked.

Sounds like the package might not be setup correctly? Alternatively, you might need to throw some more options at the configure script/edit src/Makefile to get it to find the right libraries?
